# ADT - libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file

Tags: android, linux, eclipse-adt, libstdc++

I have *Fedora 20 64-bits*, and I have a problem with *Android Development Tools*.
When I try to run project I have these errors:

```
[2014-05-11 22:08:03 - TestAp] /home/damian/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt:
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory 

[2014-05-11 22:08:03 - appcompat_v7] /home/damian/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt:
error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know that my question is also writing here but the solutions is not working with *Fedora 20*.

Answer (score 42):

I'm not totally sure about Fedora 20, but I had this same problem in Ubuntu 14.04 and installing these libraries fixed it.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

See this post:
[Android SDK - aapt error : libstdc++.so.6 cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158727/android-sdk-aapt-error-libstdc-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

Answer (score 8):

On installing NDK, on RedHat x64 these commands was helpful for me:

```
yum update
yum install libstdc++.i686
yum install compat-libstdc++-33.i686
```

Os:

```
[root@VM-Lin-CentOS ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```