# aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

We have an error during build:

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1550528231): /usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

We have two `build-tools` installed:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:43 23.0.1
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 22 11:50 23.0.3
```

`23.0.3` - downloaded and unpacked manually.

Both have `libc++.so`:

```
# find /usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/ -name 'libc++.so'
/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/lib/libc++.so
/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/lib/libc++.so
```

`/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/lib/` added to `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/maven-3.2.5/bin:/usr/local/gradle-1.5/bin:/usr/share/centrifydc/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/lib/:/opt/awscli/bin:/usr/local/sonar-runner/bin:/usr/local/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.3

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/android-sdk-23.0.2/build-tools/23.0.3/lib/l
```

What's wrong here?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
```

Comment: Is it still relevant to you? Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158727/android-sdk-aapt-error-libstdc-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Comment: Thanks, but no. Can't remember unfortunately how I solved it. By copying some libs, but which and where... Thanks anyway.